Change WordPress plugin function in 'functions.php'
I need to change the value of a function from a WordPress plugin that I'm using.
If I do it in the original plugin file, it works perfectly, but I'd rather make it in file functions.php to avoid problems on plugin update.
The original code is this:
                    <?php foreach ($products as $product) {
            if (get_option('shop-page-wp-link-target') === "2") {
                // new tab no
                $js_func = 'openUrlInSameTab';
                $target = '';
            } else {
                // new tab yes
                $js_func = 'openUrlInNewTab';
                $target = 'target="_blank"';
            }
            if (get_option('shop-page-wp-legacy-format') === "1") {
                // legacy yes
                $opening_tag = '<div onclick="' . $js_func . '(\'' . $product['link'] . '\');" class="shop-page-wp-item spwp-has-link ' . $class_name . '">';
                $opening_tag_no_link = '<div class="shop-page-wp-item ' . $class_name . '">';
                $closing_tag = '</div>';
                $btn_opening_tag = '<a style="pointer-events: none;" class="buy-link" href="' . $product['link'] . '" rel="nofollow">';
                $btn_disabled_opening_tag = '<a class="buy-link disabled">';
                $btn_closing_tag = '</a>';
            } else {
                // legacy no
                $opening_tag = '<a ' . $target . ' href="' . $product['link'] . '" class="shop-page-wp-item spwp-has-link ' . $class_name . '" rel="nofollow">';
                $opening_tag_no_link = '<a class="shop-page-wp-item ' . $class_name . '">';
                $closing_tag = '</a>';
                $btn_opening_tag = '<span class="buy-link">';
                $btn_disabled_opening_tag = '<span class="buy-link disabled">';
                $btn_closing_tag = '</span>';
            }
            ?>
            <?php if ($product['link']) {
                echo wp_kses_post($opening_tag);
            } else {
                echo wp_kses_post($opening_tag_no_link);
            }?>

I would need to change the rel="nofollow" into rel="sponsored nofollow" (two instances in the code above)
How would I go to create a filter in file functions.php to do just that?
Thanks!

Your best bet is to do what you already did and ask the plugin author, since they didn’t provide any hooks. Alternatively, you could hook core, probably at pre_kses, but that’s going to be filtering a lot of content besides your plugin. There’s output buffering, but I really hate doing that. And lastly JS might be sufficient if this is about users, not bots.

sponsored is not a valid value for the rel attribute to begin with, so why would you want to do this?

thanks for the tips! I guess my best strategy is to keep track of plugin updates and check if they updated that particular file.... the rel="sponsored" is the valid way how to mark affiliate link, Google says it's better than nofollow and now with algorythm updates I don't know which is best anymore. my SEO editor suggested I use both
